# NoClassDefFoundError when intent startActivity ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-intent

Android minSdk = 15.

I have 2 classes. First class:

```
public class InitialActivity extends Activity
{
    // some code running AsyncTask tasks
    Intent startApp = new Intent(InitialActivity.this, MainFragmentActivity.class);
    startActivity(startApp);
}
```

Second Class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
public class MainFragmentActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
}
```

In Manifest:

```
    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.myapp.afterlogin.MainFragmentActivity"
    />
```

When the intent gets to `startActivity()` the app crashes giving this:

```
06-18 09:18:27.649: W/dalvikvm(24789): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41628d40)
06-18 09:18:27.650: E/AndroidRuntime(24789): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 09:18:27.650: E/AndroidRuntime(24789): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 24789
06-18 09:18:27.650: E/AndroidRuntime(24789): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.myapp.afterlogin.MainFragmentActivity
06-18 09:18:27.650: E/AndroidRuntime(24789):    at com.example.myapp.beforelogin.InitialActivity.onResultsSucceeded(InitialActivity.java:238)
06-18 09:18:27.650: E/AndroidRuntime(24789):    at com.example.myapp.apis.GetJobList.onPostExecute(GetJobList.java:217)
06-18 09:18:27.650: E/AndroidRuntime(24789):    at com.example.myapp.apis.GetJobList.onPostExecute(GetJobList.java:1)
06-18 09:18:27.650: E/AndroidRuntime(24789):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
06-18 09:18:27.650: E/AndroidRuntime(24789):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
06-18 09:18:27.650: E/AndroidRuntime(24789):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
```

However, if the second class (`MainFragmentActivity`) extends `Activity` or `Fragment`, the app does not crash.

Comment: com.example.myapp.afterlogin.MainFragmentActivity and com.thinksai.myflexi.afterlogin.MainFragmentActivity are not the same

Comment: oops. that was a typo. fixed it

Comment: @TooManyEduardos can you show `MainFragmentActivity` full including packagename

Comment: @TooManyEduardos Have you import the correct package from the support library? Try remove all imports, and then CTRL+Shift+O to import them, be sure to import the support library

Comment: I just removed all imports and re-added them with CTRL+Shift+0.
I also just pasted the new import list to the question

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarActivity is a base class for activities that use the support library action bar features. (sdk 7+)
The ActionBar APIs were first added in Android 3.0 (API level 11).
So you don't need to use ActionBarActivity.

Extend from Activity and use this guide how to work with action bar and action items. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu

Comment: I am using the support libraries and I am targeting API level 15 though